# python while loop to break up sorted list/array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a sorted list -- actually a giant array of (x,y,z) triples sorted by x.
My goal is to break it into pieces based on ranges of x.  I've been trying

```
for triple in hugelist:  
    while triple[0] >= minx and triple[0] < maxx:  
        #do some stuff  
    # when out of that range, increase endpoints to the next range  
    minx = minx + deltax  
    maxx = maxx + deltax  
    # do some other stuff  
    # and hopefully move to next triple
```

Now of course that doesn't work because I've misused while, and I understand why.  But, I cannot figure how to while my way through the list.  hugelist is about 2 million triples to be broken into about 600 chunks.  I hope to pass through it only once, in order, if possible.

==============================

With Tim's help, using 291-point mini-list, bisect is missing the spot where maxx should go:

```
while xstart < len(heights):   
    xfinish = bisect.bisect_left(heights, (maxx, 0, 0), lo=xstart)    
    xslice = heights[xstart:xfinish]  
    print "xstart is ", xstart, " xfinish is ", xfinish  
    print "maxx is ", maxx, " xslice is ", xslice  

    maxx += deltax   
    xstart = xfinish  


xstart is  0  xfinish is  291  
maxx is  804.0  xslice is  [(803.01, 1941.84, 0.74) (803.04, 1941.88, 0.45) (803.06, 1941.25, 0.0)
 (803.07, 1941.01, 0.0) (803.07, 1941.52, 0.31) (803.09, 1941.16, 0.08)
 (803.12, 1940.05, 0.0) (803.13, 1939.72, 0.3) (803.13, 1939.86, 0.11)
 (803.13, 1940.29, 0.17)  . . .  (803.23, 1938.24, 0.2)
 (803.23, 1938.25, 0.45) (803.23, 1938.29, 0.1) (803.23, 1938.36, 0.0)
 (803.23, 1938.49, 0.0) (803.96, 1941.06, 4.21) (**803.98**, 1940.6, 4.55)
 (**804.0**, 1940.32, 4.49) (**804.01**, 1940.68, 4.6) . . .  (806.11, 1934.82, 10.64)
 (806.11, 1934.86, 10.65) (806.11, 1934.91, 10.56) (806.32, 1933.24, 4.69)]
```

Comment: Is it like this: `[(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]` or like this: `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by breaking the list into pieces?

Comment: What exactly is the stuff that you do in the `#do some stuff` part of your code? There's a chance that numpy would let you vectorize the whole thing, including the figuring out of the slice endpoints using binary search as suggested by @TimPeters. That would mean that using a `while` loop would not be the best option.

Comment: Hi Jaime, the other stuff is: further chop up the x-ranges by y-range and take a variance on each block of z's. Along with some minor organizational stuff like collecting x- y- centroids with the relevant z-variance. Trying out TimPeters' bisect this morning.  Jaime, by vectorize, do you mean re-arrange the array as 3 giant vectors [[all the x's],[all the y's],[all the z's]]?  I spent some time considering that, but I am not good enough at numpy arrays to pull it off.

Comment: The output is strange because there are no commas between tuples - did you edit it?  But most importantly, can you whittle this down so that we can reasonably see the *entire* `heights` list?  (Does it *have* to contain 291 elements?)  I can't reproduce this by guessing at values to put where the output has `. . .`.

Comment: Solved!  The commas between the tuples is exactly the problem.  While I converted the array to a list, I then mistakenly used the array as an argument instead of the list.  It is working grand now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a different, more efficient approach, exploiting that the list is sorted:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

istart = 0
while istart < len(hugelist):
    ifinish = bisect_left(hugelist, (maxx, 0, 0), lo=istart)
    # Now work on the slice hugelist[istart:ifinish].
    # It's possible that istart == ifinish, i.e. that the
    # slice is empty!
    maxx += deltax
    istart = ifinish
```

Using binary search will slash the number of comparisons needed.

Edit:  from a comment:

> It becomes very clear if you think of list indices as pointing *between*
>   elements, with 0 "to the left" of the leftmost element, and `len(hugelist)`
>   "to the right" of the rightmost element. Then `bisect_left()` returns the
>   position immediately before the first triple whose first element is >= `maxx`.

An example should really help:

```
hugelist = [(0,0,0), (1,0,0), (3,0,0), (4,1,1), (4,2,2), (5,0,0)]
maxx = 0
deltax = 1
istart = 0
while istart < len(hugelist):
    ifinish = bisect_left(hugelist, (maxx, 0, 0), lo=istart)
    # Now work on the slice hugelist[istart:ifinish].
    # It's possible that istart == ifinish, i.e. that the
    # slice is empty!
    print "for maxx =", maxx, hugelist[istart:ifinish]
    maxx += deltax
    istart = ifinish
```

And the output:

```
for maxx = 0 []
for maxx = 1 [(0, 0, 0)]
for maxx = 2 [(1, 0, 0)]
for maxx = 3 []
for maxx = 4 [(3, 0, 0)]
for maxx = 5 [(4, 1, 1), (4, 2, 2)]
for maxx = 6 [(5, 0, 0)]
```

That mostly shows endcases, which are the ones any sane reader would worry about ;-)

Comment: Wow.  Still thinking this through. I will have to try on simpler lists, but isolating the slice would allow me to grab the variance without storing anything else.  Thanks!

Comment: Yup, it's much cleaner this way :-)  It becomes very clear if you think of list indices as pointing *between* elements, with 0 "to the left" of the leftmost element, and `len(hugelist)` "to the right" of the rightmost element.  Then `bisect_left()` returns the position immediately before the first triple whose first element is >= `maxx`.

Comment: it blows right past the insertion spot.  I have it pared down to almost exactly what you wrote.                                                              
>>> while xstart < len(heights): 
 xfinish = bisect.bisect_left(heights, (maxx, 0, 0), lo=xstart)  
 xslice = heights[xstart:xfinish]
 maxx += deltax 
 xstart = xfinish

xstart is  0  xfinish is  291
maxx is  804.0  xslice is  [(803.01, 1941, 0) (803.04, 1941, 0) 
 ... omitted for length ...
 (803.23, 1938, 0) (803.96, 1941,0) (803.98, 1940, 4) **should end here**
 (804.0, 1940, 4) (804.01, 1940, 4) (804.01, 1940, 3) and so on

Comment: @KitSnicket, not your fault - formatting abilities in comments are very limited.  Perhaps add new info to your original question?

Comment: When this happens, what is the triple in `heights[xfinish]`?  And in `heights[xfinish - 1]`?  "and so on" doesn't tell me those things ;-)

Comment: xfinish is 291, the length of the list (my little practice list).  heights[xfinish-1] = (806.32, 1933.24, 4.69), the last point.  Thanks for following this up.

Comment: Hmm. I can't reproduce this. Can you whittle this down to something you can post in its *entirety*? And what type is `heights` - a Python list or some kind of `numpy` vector? Python's `bisect` hasn't changed in decades, so it's extremely unlikely to be a bug in that.

Comment: Oh, I am SURE it is not bisect; it's got to be me.  heights was dumped from an ArcGIS point shapefile into a numpy array.  When I first failed to bisect it, I converted the array to a list, in case that was the problem.  Formats are all floats, so I can't see why the comparison wouldn't work.

Comment: Yeah, it is my data. for i in heights:
 if i[0]<804: print "yes" is all yes

Comment: @KitSnicket, LOL! I'm baffled. I could have sworn your output shows values larger than 804 ;-) What's going on here?!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `if` to check if `triple[0]` is within the desired range. There's no need for an inner loop. If the list is sorted by the x-values then there is no need to compare to a minimum; just check it is below the maximum.

```
for triple in hugelist:  
    if triple[0] < maxx:  
        #do some stuff  
    else:
        maxx = maxx + deltax  
        # do some other stuff
```

Depending on what you are trying to do, you might also look into [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

EDIT: If the aim, as you say in a comment, is to get the variances of the z values within each range then you could do something like:

```
z_variances = []
z_group = []
maxx = deltax
for x, y, z in huge_list:
    if x < maxx:
        z_group.append(z)
    else:
        z_variances.append(var(z_group))
        z_group = [z]
        maxx += deltax
```

Or using `groupby`:

```
z_variances = []
for _, group in itertools.groupby(huge_list, lambda x: int(x / deltax)):
    z_variances.append(var(z for x, y, z in group))
```

Comment: stuart, I need the variance in the z's for each range.

Comment: I am still thinking about your suggested "if" . . . I had ruled it out, but now I have to remember why!  :)

Comment: thanks, I just couldn't see it -- was letting the sort order bias me towards while.

Answer (score 1):

First, create a sample numpy array:

```
>>> alen=300000
>>> huge=np.arange(alen).reshape(alen/3,3)
>>> huge
array([[     0,      1,      2],
       [     3,      4,      5],
       [     6,      7,      8],
       ..., 
       [299991, 299992, 299993],
       [299994, 299995, 299996],
       [299997, 299998, 299999]])
```

This syntax will give you the first column:

```
>>> huge[:,0]
array([     0,      3,      6, ..., 299991, 299994, 299997])
```

Since you state that the sub arrays are sorted, you can use numpy.searchsorted to separate the larger array into buckets.

Let's break into thirds:

```
>>> minx=huge[-1][0]/3
>>> maxx=huge[-1][0]*2/3
>>> minx
99999
>>> maxx
199998
```

Just test the condition you want against that for the triples that are in the range you want using np.searchsorted:

```
>>> np.searchsorted(huge[:,0],[minx,maxx])
array([33333, 66666])
```

Then slice `huge` into the desired buckets:

```
>>> buckets=np.searchsorted(huge[:,0],[minx,maxx])
>>> bucket1=huge[0:buckets[0]]
>>> bucket2=huge[buckets[0]:buckets[1]]
>>> bucket3=huge[buckets[1]:]
>>> bucket1
array([[    0,     1,     2],
       [    3,     4,     5],
       [    6,     7,     8],
       ..., 
       [99990, 99991, 99992],
       [99993, 99994, 99995],
       [99996, 99997, 99998]])
>>> bucket2
array([[ 99999, 100000, 100001],
       [100002, 100003, 100004],
       [100005, 100006, 100007],
       ..., 
       [199989, 199990, 199991],
       [199992, 199993, 199994],
       [199995, 199996, 199997]])
>>> bucket3
array([[199998, 199999, 200000],
       [200001, 200002, 200003],
       [200004, 200005, 200006],
       ..., 
       [299991, 299992, 299993],
       [299994, 299995, 299996],
       [299997, 299998, 299999]])
```

You can also use np.histogram:

```
>>> edges=np.histogram(huge[:,0],[0,minx,maxx,huge[-1][0]])[1]
>>> b1=huge[edges[0]:edges[1]]
>>> b2=huge[edges[1]:edges[2]]
>>> b3=huge[edges[2]:edges[3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just "up to x", use `itertools.takewhile`:

```
import itertools

li = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),(10,11,12),(13,14,15)]

list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x[0] < 10,li))
Out[78]: [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
```

If you want to specify groups for the whole collection, it's `itertools.groupby`:

```
def grouper(x):
    if x < 5:
        return 0
    if x < 11:
        return 1
    return 2

for i,g in itertools.groupby(li,lambda x: grouper(x[0])):
    print('group {}: {}'.format(i,list(g)))

group 0: [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
group 1: [(7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12)]
group 2: [(13, 14, 15)]
```

Comment: I just noticed you have this tagged with `numpy`.  Is your data actually in a numpy array?  This answer is inappropriate for numpy.  (this is why you should provide sample data)

Comment: yes, sorry, numpy, but not necessarily so: could be made into a list